# JAVAMAIL get Content with InputStream

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to get the content Text of a Message in my Android App with an InputStream, because there I can get a line Separator. I'm getting the following Exception when I'm trying it:

*java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.io.InputStream*

This is my Code:

```
Object o = message.getContent();

InputStream is = (InputStream)o;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(line);
}
String everything = sb.toString();
```

Do you know what the problem is? In every Javamail - Thread you can read that this Method runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Message.getInputStream method.